# access violation in C CUDA code

Tags: c, cuda

The code compiles with no errors, but access violation message comes up when debugging. Can any one please point out what is wrong with the code below?

My code actually runs 1000 iterations of 1000 instances of the same equation
    its a recursive nonlinear equation. The aim is simply to appreciate the ability
    to run multiple(iterative)equations in parallel.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <time.h> 

#define TOTAL_THREADS 1024
#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 256
#define TOTAL_BLOCKS 4
#define VALUES_PER_THREAD 1000
#define THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD 15

__global__ void my_compute(float *y_d, float *theta_d, float *u_d) 
{
   int offset = ((blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x) * VALUES_PER_THREAD;
   int theta_offset = ((blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x) * THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD;

   for (int i = 7; i < 1000; i++) {
      y_d[offset + i] = theta_d[theta_offset + 0] * y_d[offset + i - 1] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 1] * y_d[offset + i - 3] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 2] * u_d[offset + i - 5] * u_d[offset + i - 4] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 3] + 
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 4] * u_d[offset + i - 6] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 5] * u_d[offset + i - 4] * y_d[offset + i - 6] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 6] * u_d[offset + i - 7] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 7] * u_d[offset + i - 7] * u_d[offset + i - 6] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 8] * y_d[offset + i - 4] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 9] * y_d[offset + i - 5] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 10] * u_d[offset + i - 4] * y_d[offset + i - 5] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 11] * u_d[offset + i - 4] * y_d[offset + i - 2] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 12] * u_d[offset + i - 7] * u_d[offset + i - 3] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 13] * u_d[offset + i - 5] +
                        theta_d[theta_offset + 14] * u_d[offset + i - 4];
   }
}

int main(void) 
{
   float y[1000000];
   FILE * fpoo;
   FILE * u;
   float theta[15000];
   float u_data[1000000];
   float *y_d;
   float *theta_d;
   float *u_d;
   cudaEvent_t start, stop;
   float time;

   cudaEventCreate(&start);
   cudaEventCreate(&stop);

   //memory allocation
   cudaMalloc((void **) &y_d, 1000000 * sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc((void **) &theta_d, 15000 * sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc((void **) &u_d, 1000000 * sizeof(float));
   cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

   // importing data for theta and input of model//
   fpoo = fopen("c:\\Fly_theta.txt", "r");
   u = fopen("c:\\Fly_u.txt", "r");

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
         fscanf(fpoo, "%f\n", &theta[15 * i + j]);
   } 
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
         fscanf(u, "%f\n", &u_data[1000 * i + j]);
   }
   //initialising past input with the value of zero//
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
         y[8 * i + j] = 0;
   }
   cudaMemcpy(y_d, y, 1000000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   cudaMemcpy(theta_d, theta, 15000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(u_d, u_data, 1000000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   //calling kernel function//
   my_compute <<< 4, 256 >>> (y_d, theta_d, u_d);

   cudaMemcpy(y, y_d, 1000000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
         printf("%f", y[1000 * i + j]);
   } 
   cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
   cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
   cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
   cudaEventDestroy(start);
   cudaEventDestroy(stop);
   printf("Time to generate:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

   cudaFree(y_d);
   cudaFree(theta_d);
   cudaFree(u_d);

   fclose(u);
   fclose(fpoo);

   //fclose();
   _getche();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try *spaces* and *indentation*. This is a pain to read.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry about that, the bulk of y_d[offset+i] is actually a single equation. in my actual code its literally a single line.

Comment: I don't see where `blockDim` or `blockIdx` are declared.

Comment: @jomizu: I didn't mean that line -- I meant everywhere else. The code is really just very hard to read and parse mentally.

Comment: Which line causes the access violation? And could you still please fix your indentation. You can see what the formatted post looks like at the moment. 4 spaces per level would to the trick.

Comment: @Bart it doesn't say, a dialogue box just comes up with the message after debugging.

Comment: @jsn. sorry didnt know i had to do that, thought calling the kernel function with the parameter of the blocks and thread will enable the runtime to set that. pls direct me on how to define that.

Comment: The code is correct. blockDim, blockIdx, and threadIdx are built in values. You should break your primary line into multiple independent expressions. This will greatly improve readability, debugging, and often results in better code generation.

Comment: @ouah i just tried that and the values being printed were all zeros. but subsequently used dynamic memory allocation, but now get some values which are not right.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a stack overflow.

Try adding a `static` specifier to your array declarations:

```
static float y[1000000];
static float theta[15000];
static float u_data[1000000];
```

Comment: You could consider dynamically allocating the host memory. Placing MBs of data on the stack is never a good idea.

Comment: @GregSmith I have now done that, but i'm getting some weird results which are not the anticipated values.

Comment: @Eugene pls how do i get it to be no more than 14999, and does that mean every other memory allocation is ok?

Answer (score 1):

I tried you code with cuda-gdb from Toolkit 5.0 with integrated cuda-memcheck.

What it shown me is that on the thread (232,0,0) of block (3,0,0) theta_offset is 15000 - and from my expection of you code it looks like it should never be more then 14999 (theta_d size is 15000 so that is max index that can be used)

Note that 4 blocks * 256 threads * 15 elements/thread = 15360.

Comment: You get theta_offset to 15000 by ((3 * 256) + 232) * 15

Comment: You allocations seem to be ok, I don't have data files so I commented out code that reads them. The problem is purely arithmetic.

Comment: i'm happy to send you the data files if thats ok.

Comment: I don't think I need the data yet :) Have you found the problem I am speaking about? Are you using cuda-gdb for debugging? Use "set cuda memcheck on". You can set the same flag in the Nsight Eclipse Edition UI in the debug configuration dialog.

Comment: i'm not using Nsight Eclipse. i was advised i wouldn't be needing it. just using VS 2008(V9). I changed my offset to             int         offset =((3 * 256)  + 232)*VALUES_PER_THREAD;
int theta_offset = ((3 * 256) + 232)*THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD; is this right?

Comment: You don't need to hardcode the offset. You need to make sure you don't go beyond array bounds. ((3 * 256) + 232)*VALUES_PER_THREAD is what makes you do an out-of-bounds access. I think, an easiest way would be to enclose "for" in "if (theta_offset < 15000)". Please note that I am not trying to ensure the algorythm is correct - so you need to validate that it still does what it should.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene is spot on. The problem is the original allocation for theta_d :

The byte size of theta_d should be :

```
 THREADS_PER_BLOCK * TOTAL_BLOCKS * THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD * ELEMENT_SIZE = 
 256 * 4 * 15 * 4 =  61440
```

to ensure that the access pattern you have selected can access all elements of the array. In the app, 
theta_d is declared as :

```
cudaMalloc((void **) &theta_d, 15000 * sizeof(float));
```

Effectively, theta_d is only 60000 bytes in size. As a result, the kernel will hit errors for all accesses past byte 60000.

One solution would be to size the allocation based on the constants you have already #defined.If you replace 15000 with "THREADS_PER_BLOCK * TOTAL_BLOCKS * THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD", it will size the allocation correctly. Try the following main function:

```
int main(void) 
{
   float y[1000000];
   FILE * fpoo;
   FILE * u;
   float theta[THREADS_PER_BLOCK * TOTAL_BLOCKS * THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD];
   float u_data[1000000];
   float *y_d;
   float *theta_d;
   float *u_d;
   cudaEvent_t start, stop;
   float time;

   cudaEventCreate(&start);
   cudaEventCreate(&stop);

   //memory allocation
   cudaMalloc((void **) &y_d, 1000000 * sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc((void **) &theta_d, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * TOTAL_BLOCKS * THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD* sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc((void **) &u_d, 1000000 * sizeof(float));
   cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

   // importing data for theta and input of model//
   fpoo = fopen("c:\\Fly_theta.txt", "r");
   u = fopen("c:\\Fly_u.txt", "r");

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
         fscanf(fpoo, "%f\n", &theta[15 * i + j]);
   } 
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
         fscanf(u, "%f\n", &u_data[1000 * i + j]);
   }
   //initialising past input with the value of zero//
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
         y[8 * i + j] = 0;
   }
   cudaMemcpy(y_d, y, 1000000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   cudaMemcpy(theta_d, theta, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * TOTAL_BLOCKS * THETA_VALUES_PER_THREAD* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(u_d, u_data, 1000000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   //calling kernel function//
   my_compute <<< 4, 256 >>> (y_d, theta_d, u_d);

   cudaMemcpy(y, y_d, 1000000 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
         printf("%f", y[1000 * i + j]);
   } 
   cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
   cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
   cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
   cudaEventDestroy(start);
   cudaEventDestroy(stop);
   printf("Time to generate:  %3.1f ms \n", time);

   cudaFree(y_d);
   cudaFree(theta_d);
   cudaFree(u_d);

   fclose(u);
   fclose(fpoo);

   //fclose();
   _getche();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code is indeed correct. the 'fopen for loops' for reading data from file was not 
    reading data as expected. so I changed it to the following loop below. my code now
   runs perfectly. thanks to everyone that contributed.

// importing data for theta and input of model

```
fpoo= fopen("c:\\Fly_theta.txt","r");

u= fopen("c:\\Fly_u.txt","r");


        for(int j=0;j<15;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fpoo,"%f\n",&theta[j]);
            }
         for(int i=1;i<1000;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<15;j++)
             {
                theta[15*i+j]=theta[j];
             }
         }
        for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
            {
                fscanf(u,"%f\n",&u_data[j]);
            }
        for(int i=1;i<1000;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<1000;j++)
             {
                u_data[1000*i+j]=u_data[j];
             }
        }
```